# Merging hashes in Ruby not working as intended

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to reproduce an example in a Ruby tutorial of merging two hashes. However, using the "merge" method does not have the desired effect. When I run the following script:

```
capitals={'New York' => 'Albany','California' => 'Sacramento'}
more_capitals={'Texas' => 'Austin', 'Alaska' => 'Fairbanks'}

capitals.merge(more_capitals)

capitals.each do |state,capital|
    puts "#{capital} is the capital of #{state}"
end
```

I get this result:

```
Albany is the capital of New York
Sacramento is the capital of California
```

(see also screen grab from repl.it below). I would however also expect the output to contain "Austin is the capital of Texas" and "Fairbanks is the capital of Alaska" if the merging of the "capitals" and "more_capitals" hashes were carried out correctly. Why is this not the case?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the non-destructive version of [`merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge), which returns a new Hash you need to assign and use.

```
new_capitals = capitals.merge(more_capitals)
```

Or, you can use [`merge!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21), which does it in place:

```
capitals.merge!(more_capitals)
```

Comment: To clarify the terms, here "non-destructive" means "makes a copy" as compared to the in-place, modifying version with `!`.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, In addition to [@Kristján's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36774056/3437900),

Sometimes you might also encounter this situation and get astonished

```
 > capitals      = { 'New York' => 'Albany', 'California' => 'Sacramento'}
 > more_capitals = {:'New York' => 'Albany', 'Alaska' => 'Fairbanks'}
 > capitals.merge!(more_capitals)
```

and

```
capitals.each do |state,capital|
    puts "#{capital} is the capital of #{state}"
end
```

**Output**

```
Albany is the capital of New York
Sacramento is the capital of California
Albany is the capital of New York
Fairbanks is the capital of Alaska
```

**Question**

Why is `merge!` not working, its supposed to merge the values with same keys. i.e. `New York`

**Explanation:**
In `Ruby`'s `Hash`, `symbol`, `string`, `array`, `hash` and `Integer` are considered as separate keys.

```
  > new_hash = {:'a' => 'value with string symbol as a key', 'a' => 'value with string as a key', [:a] => 'value with array as a key', {a: 'key_hash'} => 'value with hash a key'}

  > new_hash[:a]
 => "value with string symbol as a key" 
  > new_hash['a']
 => "value with string as a key" 
  > new_hash[[:a]]
 => "value with array as a key" 
  > new_hash[{a: 'key_hash'}]
 => "value with hash a key"
```